# How to deploy RailsPDF on Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pdf, heroku

I am trying to deploy RailsPDF on a Heroku app but don't know where to start, as it requires Node.js / npm.

We need to generate PDF with Rails, and they must include JavaScript-generated diagrams. The latter pretty much ruled out Prawn, and wicked_pdf / wkhtmltopdf turned out to be extremely resource-heavy and instable at least in our environment (not to mention that the PDFs were often incomplete).

I've been toying around with a relatively new gem, [RailsPDF](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_pdf). Like wkhtmltopdf it renders views directly to PDF files, but with a current Chrome version through Puppeteer / [RelaxedJS](https://github.com/RelaxedJS/ReLaXed). So it's flexible but also more stable.

Locally I can run it fine. What I haven't figured out though is how to deploy this on a Heroku Rails app, as [Node / npm are required to install RelaxedJS](https://github.com/igorkasyanchuk/rails_pdf#install-relaxedjs).

How can I use a Node.js / npm dependency in my Ruby app on Heroku?

Comment: you would be using js gems inside rails app only right? you won't need node/npm in the machine.

Comment: you just deploy the app , heroku takes care of dependencies .

Comment: The local installation requires npm (I've edited my question to include a link to the RailsPDF installation instructions) and AFAIK this might be beyond Heroku's dependency handling. Or am I wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [multiple buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app):

1. Set your main buildpack

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:set heroku/ruby
   ```
2. Add the Node.js buildpack

   ```
   heroku buildpacks:add --index 1 heroku/nodejs
   ```

   Make sure to include a `package.json` in the root of your project since the Node.js buildpack requires one.
3. Verify that you have the correct buildpacks configured by running `.heroku buildpacks`. You should see Node.js first and Ruby second. The last build buildpack should be your main one.

The next time you deploy your application you should see your Node.js dependencies being built followed by your Ruby dependencies. `node` and whatever `dependencies` you have will be available at runtime (though [by default `devDependencies` won't be](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#package-installation)).

It sounds like you will also need to add the [Chrome buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome) and the [Chromedriver buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver). You may need to provide longer arguments than the short `heroku/foo` ones above; see the bottom of each buildpack page for details.

Remember to keep Ruby as your last buildpack as you add more.

Comment: Thank you! Having no experience with Node.js so far, I'm guessing that in the `package.json` I would only list `relaxedjs`, correct? Then npm should install it with its own dependencies on the Heroku server, automatically when I deploy the app, correct?

Comment: Yes, something like that. How did you install ReLaXed on your local machine? Did you use `npm`, `yarn`, or do something else?

Comment: Yes, I used `npm` and it's now a subfolder in the app. That was only temporary and is obviously messy with git and deployment etc.; now knowing how it should be done on Heroku it would make more sense to just install RelaxedJS globally on my local machine, and follow your instructions above for deployment on the server.

Comment: By "subfolder in the app" I guess you mean `node_modules/`? That shouldn't be in your repo. Run `npm init` in the root of your repository, then `npm install relaxedjs`. That should create a reasonable `package.json` and `package-lock.json`, both of which should be committed to the repo.

Comment: Phantastic, thank you! I got it to work; one important change to the gem was to only run chromedriver with the "--no-sandbox" parameter. Unfortunately my slug size more than tripled to well over 300 MB, but that's an issue for another day.